# How to freeze a falling rigid body animation for good?

Tags: keyframes, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation, rigidbody

What I've been trying to do is to make a simple bowl in which candies fall using the the rigid body animations for both. But after say certain key frames I want it to be the final(or rather the default) model, as if it was never animated and this itself was the default model. I want to use this model in another file.

I can't find any option like the cloth simulator where you can simply apply it and it finalizes. Any help would be appreciated.

I'll post pictures in a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Select the object(s) you want, select the frame you want in the timeline, then in the header menu > *Object > Rigid Body > Bake to Keyframes* and choose the frame(s) you want in the pop-up.

Comment: Yup it worked thanks alot!